# How to support landscape mode on Ipad in UIImageView?

Tags: swift

I need to use **Launchscreen.storyboard**. I have one imageView there. I want to use an image for portrait mode and an image for landscape mode only on iPad. How to do that? How to support landscape mode in UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with "Vary for traits". In portrait mode height is Regular and width is Compact "wC hR" and in landscape height is Compact and width is Compact "wC hC".

So you can add two images view and then you should add the correct Traits by clicking on the "+". Add traits to your image views with the correct Traits [image]

I wish I can help you.

> EDIT : Only for iPhone, iPad has both "wR hR" in portrait and landscape

Comment: iPad has "wR hR" in both modes (Portrait and Landscape)

Comment: My aim is replace image only for iPad for landscape orientation

Comment: Oh ok, you didn't mention it's on iPad, so I agree that my answer is not right in your case